# how to use displacement maps on Eevee Blender 2.8

Tags: eevee-render-engine

how to use displacement maps on Eevee ? is it a coming feature. Because right now on 2.8 I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

It's working as usual, like this:
[image]

I have a subdivided plane here, then i went into the modifiers tab, added a displace modifier, then you click new texture, after this, go to the texture tab:

[image]

In here you can either choose an existing image to displace your mesh or a noise texture already available:

[image]

Then, when you leave edit mode, you should have your mesh with the displacement that you chose:
[image]

In this case, Voronoi. You should always download the latest version of blender 2.8 in the experimental tab on the blender.org website, maybe the version that you're using didn't have the displacement availabe :)

Comment: But not micro displacement for detailed displacement maps

Comment: You mean with the node editor?

Comment: Eevee does not yet have an equivalent to Cycles' render time displacement. It is not able to use displacement shaders to actually modify geometry, only for bump mapping.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that, maybe in future updates? Either way, it's a really cool way to preview cycles!