# How to add Displace Modifier from height map

Tags: displacement

Im trying to add Height to my subdivided plane based on heightmap texture. I found this solution([how to use displacement maps on Eevee Blender 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121889/how-to-use-displacement-maps-on-eevee-blender-2-8?newreg=4b3e644bd88c4a1096b3e07e490f5082)) and its exactly what i want. But for some reason i dont have the option to "open" or add texture. Did the work flow change or im missing something? Im using blender 2.83.2.

[image]

Comment: Press on texture> **New**. Or use the square at the bottom left of your image (red square with black and red squares). Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27451/landscape-topography-from-grayscale-image/27454#27454 the interface has changed slighlty, but the procedure is the same.

Comment: I see. Thank you!